# In Groovy, how do I remove a property from a nested Map?

Tags: grails, dictionary, groovy

I'm writing a test in Grails that ensures the incoming JSON from a client contains all required fields. The Map looks something like:

```
def map = [
    customer: [
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        id: '123',
    ],
    orderNumber: '123456',
    paymentInfo: [
        type: 'paypal',
        amount: '1200',
        currency: 'USD'
    ]
]
```

So in other words, the `customer` and `paymentInfo` keys are maps themselves with subkeys.

In my test, I'd like to remove each key and subkey to ensure that input validation is working. I did something like this:

```
// test 1
map.remove('orderNumber')
def result = service.performAction(map)
assert result == ServiceCall.ValidationError

// test 2
map.remove('customer.firstName')
def result = service.performAction(map)
assert result == ServiceCall.ValidationError
```

Test 1 works and properly removes the `orderNumber` key, but Test 2 does not remove the `firstName` subkey. I know that I can use `map.customer.remove(firstName)` and it will remove the subkey properly, but I"m trying to make the test generic enough so that I only have to pass in an array of strings and they keys and subkeys will be removed properly, something like:

```
def array = ['orderNumber', 'customer.firstName', 'customer.lastName', etc...]

array.each {
    map.remove(it)
    def result = service.performAction(map)
    assert result == ServiceCall.ValidationError
}
```

Is it possible to remove the subkeys this way, and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, 'customer.firstName' is NOT a key of the toplevel map, so it won't work.  You can do something to parse the keys that you pass in, instead.

try this?

```
array.each {
   def levels = it.tokenize('.')
   if ( levels.size() == 1 ) {
      map.remove(levels[0])
   } else if ( level.size() == 2 ) {
      map.get(levels[0]).remove(levels[1])
   } // else etc.
   def result = service.performAction(map)
   assert result == ServiceCall.ValidationError
}
```

Note, I made this very non-generic depthwise...  you could easily write a generic function to remove the nth level map property.  But if you know you only need to go 2 or even 3 deep, something like this should work just fine without a bunch of harder-to-read generic code.

If you absolutely want to go through the trouble of having it work for arbitrarily deep sub-maps:

```
array.each {
   def levels = it.tokenize('.')
   if ( levels.size() == 1 ) {
      map.remove(levels[0])
   } else  {
      def ref = map
      levels[0..-2].each {
          ref = ref[it]
      }
      ref.remove(levels[-1])
   }
   def result = service.performAction(map)
   assert result == ServiceCall.ValidationError
}
```

I do notice that your "map" is not restored in-between tests...  Your original test didn't do this either, so my code behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Spock for testing, so it does restore the map in between.

Comment: Yes it did, although I ended up using string.split() and array notation instead.